# Migrating from CVXPY directly to Solver or How to Make CVXPY run faster

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, solver, scipy-optimize, cvxpy

I am trying to solve a convex optimization problem very quickly with python. My problem looks like this:

[image]

with p, m, z and o being arrays of values. Z being the one to solve for. and both p and z being from 0-1 inclusive and the sum of all z adding up to 1

After some searching, people recommended trying cvxpy and using trying their different solvers. Which I went on to do. Here is what my basic solve code looks like in cvxpy format:

```
z = cp.Variable(num_values_z, nonneg=True)

combo_matrix = cp.multiply(z, o)
combo_matrix2 = cp.matmul(combo_matrix, m.T).T
log_sum = cp.sum(cp.multiply(cp.log(combo_matrix2), p))
obj = cp.Maximize(log_sum)

constraint_zero_one = [z <= 1]
constraint_sum_one = [cp.sum(z) == 1]
constraint_two = [p <= 1]
```

(also p and z are set to be non-negative)

Thing thing is, when I solve a problem with verbose turned on it tells me that the solution was found in around 200 microseconds, which is very fast and a time that I am trying to get close to. In practice however, running 10k iterations takes about 30 seconds, which is more than ten times slower than the solving alone takes. The vast majority of that time is compiling.

Doing some reading of cvxpy documentation, cvxpy was [apparently not designed for speed at all](https://ask.cvxr.com/t/how-to-speed-up-run-time/5602). It also seems that cvxpy is spending time and resources checking if the problem is convex, when I know for a fact mine is by definition. cvxpy itself suggested I mitigate this by setting my inputs as parameters, which I did, but this sped it up an imperceptible amount.

So next I started looking into cutting out the middleman and trying to interface with the solvers that worked fastest on cvxpy (which turned out to be CLARABEL and ECOS) directly. But according to [Clarabel](https://oxfordcontrol.github.io/ClarabelDocs/stable/) documentation it solves problems in the format:

[image]

I have no clue how to set my problem in that format. It *must* be possible because cvxpy is able to do it, but I'm at a loss for how I can do it. The [clarabel documentation example](https://oxfordcontrol.github.io/ClarabelDocs/stable/python/getting_started_py/) looks nothing like my problem and I can't find any more information on it.

Does anyone know how I can input an optimization problem like mine in a format that is directly readable by a solver like Clarabel or ECOS? Or alternately, is there a way to speed up cvxpy to have comparable solving speed? Or is there a third option that I don't know about. I'd welcome any and all information you can give me on the matter. Thanks for your help!

***EDIT**: On request, here are some examples of p,m and o data:

```
p:
[1.         5.5        5.99       5.9        6.4        5.8
 5.9        1.85       2.07       1.21276596 1.19230769 1.19607843
 1.17857143 1.2        1.19607843 2.03092784 1.83333333]

m:
[[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0]]

o:
[0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667]
```

Comment: Show example p, m, o data.

Comment: Assuming z is your only variable, and conceding that I am by no means a mathematician, I don't think your problem can be coerced into the required quadratic form without approximating the logarithm with something something like a Taylor Series expansion on the logarithm (which...maybe if m and o are small?).

Comment: @Reinderien added examples to the end of my post

Comment: @A10 that's my instant reaction. However, cvxpy is able to use the clarabel solver to solve this exact problem somehow.

Comment: Without knowing what your speed constraints are, [the Gekko Optimization suite](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has some decent open-source MIP solvers.

Comment: @A10 thanks for the heads up. I'll try to reformulate my equations in Gecko syntax and see what kind of performance I get. At a glance thought the solvers gecko has don't seem to be optimized for convex problems though.

Comment: Maximizing ``f(x)`` is the same as maximizing a new variable ``t`` subject to a constraint ``t<=f(x)``, in case this is the issue you are asking for. This is the standard reformulation trick which allows you to express every objective as linear. In your case with logarithms the latter inequality will have some representation using exponential cones. Conic modeling is explained in https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/index.html, for logarithms esp. chapter 5.

Comment: And yes, CVXPY spends some time compiling the problem, but you can use parameters to create a parameterized problem which you can feed with different data, which can reduce the preprocessing time for actual solves.